# Powerhsell - ad extract and filter the result

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I folks,
I'm looking for and ad extract but I'm not getting the restult I want in the extracted file.

I'm running this powershell command, if I remove the "select-string" switch I get what I want:

```
import-module activedirectory
get-aduser  -filter * -properties *| Select-Object -Property CN,co,ExtensionAttribute10,extensionAttribute11,extensionAttribute12,Name,SamAccountName,Description,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,accountexpirationdate,<#Manager#>distinguishedname,Title,Department,whenCreated,Enabled,Organization  |Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-String -Pattern "regular","remote","shopfloor","admin" |Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -path "u:\theOutFile2.txt"
```

As soon as i use the `Select-String -Pattern` my csv is getting wierd.

Instead of having info like

```
CN;"co";"distinguishedname";"ExtensionAttribute10";"extensionAttribute11";"extensionAttribute12";"Name";"SamAccountName";"Description";"EmailAddress";"LastLogonDate";"Manager";"Title";"Department";"whenCreated";"Enabled";"Organization"
```

My CSV is like this:

```
IgnoreCase;"LineNumber";"Line";"Filename";"Path";"Pattern";"Context";"Matches"
```

and all my line are write like

```
True;"1";"@{CN=accountValue; co=; ExtensionAttribute10=; extensionAttribute11=; extensionAttribute12=; Name=accountValue; SamAccountName=accountValue; Description=;
```

So the main goal of this script is to retrive users accounts that are in Multiple OU with string "regular","remote","shopfloor","admin"

I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert in you pipe before `export-Csv` :

```
...|Where-Object {$_.CN -like "*regular*"-or $_.CN -like "*remote*" -or $_.CN -like "*shopfloor*"}| ...
```

Comment: Yes my friend it works thanks for your time it is price less. Have a  nice day